# Ruby - remove lowercase letters

Tags: ruby, regex

Let say I have this string: `a = "Vallås centrum HALMSTAD"`
And I would like to remove all lowercase, whitespace and the first uppercase letter so I only have a string with `a => "HALMSTAD"`

I tried something like this:

```
a = "Vallås centrum HALMSTAD"
b = a.gsub(/[:lower:]/, "")
puts b
```

But I get this output: `a => "Vaås cntum HALMSTAD"`

any ideas on how to to do this?

Comment: You say you want all lowercase letters removed yet in your example you are removing a capital `V`. Is this what you are intending?

Comment: You're also not removing spaces

Comment: I would like to remove everything and the only output I want is "HALMSTAD"

Comment: Is `HALMSTAD` always at the end of the string?

Comment: @TimPietzcker. No, but there are always at the end of the string uppcase city names. Examples: "Djurgården 18 LUND", "Gågatan 23B MALMÖ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = "Vallås centrum ISN'T blah Blah HALMSTAD AND "
b = a.gsub(/\b[A-Z]?[^A-Z\s']+\s*\b/, '')
puts b
```

This should take care of most lower case words but you need to deal with other possible cases where you have punctuation symbols, question marks, exclamation marks, non-ASCII characters, etc...

You can fiddle with this [here](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/941fb)

---

In view of  @TimPietzcker's comment of non-ASCII characters, you could replace the `A-Z` with the POSIX bracket expression `[[:upper:]]`

---

**UPDATE**:
This would be a more complete solution:

Regex to find most lowercase words (This can still be extended for more symbols):

```
\b(?:[^\s]?[[:lower:]][^\s]?)+\s*\b[?!]?
```

Test the regex [here](http://rubular.com/r/wbfe73F9zH)

Ruby Code:

```
a = "Vallås centrum ISN'T blah Blah HALMSTAD AND BlaG and bLag's? FINISH "
b = a.gsub(/\b(?:[^\s]?[[:lower:]][^\s]?)+\s*\b[?!]?/, '')
puts b
```

Fiddle with the code [here](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/941fb/3)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should match the uppercase words (including consecutive words and possible punctuation within them) and replace the rest with empty string.

Regex for this would

```
\b([A-Z']+\s*)\b
```

This would match and capture all UPPERCASE words including consecutive ones.

[Rubular link](http://rubular.com/r/vfnO75DtLa)

Sample string considered:

> Vallås centrum ISN'T blah Blah HALMSTAD AND BLAh

And this matches:

> ISN'T
>   HALMSTAD AND

Comment: How do I do this in ruby, b = a.gsub(/(\b(?:[A-Z']+\s*)\b)/, "") and got this: Vallås centrum @Kash

Comment: Careful, this fails as soon as there is a non-ASCII uppercase letter in the word you're looking for.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - Updated my other answer (accepted one) to address that and some other issues like considering `BLaH` to be a lowercase word.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you want to "only remove the lowercase characters" (and keep the spaces), or "only keep the uppercase characters" (and lose the spaces). I'd suggest maybe the following is closer to what you're after?

```
a = "Vallås centrum HALMSTAD"
b = a.gsub(/[^[:upper:]]+/, "")
puts b # => "VHALMSTAD"
```

Comment: Sorry if I have made my self more clear, I would like to remove everything and only have "HALMSTAD" left. So I have to first remove the first uppercase letter and then remove all the downcase. Do you know what I mean, @Gareth

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
your_string.split.last
```